# Should webservices return a value even if the action performed doesn't return a value?

Tags: web-services

Suppose that the action performed by the procedure , which is called by the webservice , is equivalent to a `void` method , should it always return a value anyway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WSDL point of view you have two choices:

1:

```
<wsdl:types>
  ...
  <xs:element name="method1" type="x:MyType1" />
  ...

<wsdl:message name="msg1_1">
  <wsdl:part name="input" element="tns:method1" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="MyInterface">
  <wsdl:operation name="method1">
    <wsdl:input name="req" message="tns:msg1_1" />
  </wsdl:operation>
  ...
```

2:

```
<wsdl:types>
  ...
  <xs:element name="method2" type="x:MyType2" />
  <xs:element name="method2Response">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ...

<wsdl:message name="msg2_1">
  <wsdl:part name="input" element="tns:method2" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="msg2_1">
  <wsdl:part name="output" element="tns:method2Response" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="MyInterface">
  <wsdl:operation name="method2">
    <wsdl:input name="req" message="tns:msg2_1" />
    <wsdl:output name="res" message="tns:msg2_2" />
  </wsdl:operation>
  ...
```

With option `1` you get *One-way Operation* which may sometimes be a problem becase the client's call returns without the knowledge of comleting the server-side method.

With option `2` you have normal *Request-response Operation*, you just get (almost) empty SOAP response.

(all above examples use *document/literal/wrapped* convention)

From implementation point of view, if you use e.g. Apache CXF with JAX-WS you end up with standard, void-returning methods.